# How two UInt8 variables are added in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift2, swift-playground

Say there are two variables:

```
let number1 : UInt8 = 100;
let number2 : UInt8 = 100;
```

You add and print them

```
print(number1 + number2)  //This prints 200
```

Now define one more

```
let number3 : UInt8 = 200;
```

And try to add now

```
print(number1 + number3)  // Throws execution was interrupted
```

I understand that the sum of number1 and number3 would be out of range of UInt8 but explicit casting also does not help, for example following line also gives the same error:

```
print(UInt8(number1 + number3)) // Throws execution was interrupted
```

The way I found was to do the following:

```
print(Int(number1) + Int(number3))
```

Is there a better way of adding UInt8 number when their sum goes out of range?

Comment: Store them as `Int` but `print((number1 + number3) & 0xff)` would at least avoid the exception but keep the sum within `UInt8` range.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when preserving the type ?

Comment: UInt8(number1 + number3) couldn't help for two reasons: 1. number1 + number3 already crashes because it is an overflow (300 doesn't fit). At that point it's too late to avoid the crash by casting. 2. If you had added two Ints then the cast to UInt8 would crash because again 300 doesn't fit.

Comment: Swift _intentionally_ detects values that go out of range, so there is nothing better than casting both values to Int (or Int16, or UInt16 and so on).

Comment: Yes there is; storing them as `Int` in the first place.

Comment: Unfortunately the struct where the UInt8 var is stored belongs to someone else hence I can't change it :(
Basically the UInt8s denote RGB values which might be the reason it is stored like that.
I am applying some image processing algorithms where I need to manipulate those values but facing these basic issues while doing simple arithmetic operations.

Comment: @girish-k-gupta : Then whatever you are doing is correct :) Int(number1) + Int(number3)

Comment: If the `UInt8` values represent RGB values (in the sense of image analysis), does it really make sense that the sum of two such values yields non-valid RGB value (e.g. `let sumOfRGBValues = Int(number1) + Int(number3) // = 300`). Perhaps you are rather looking to truncate the sum of two valid RGB numbers to the range of `UInt8`? Say `100+200` truncates to `255` whereas  `100-200` truncates to `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've said casting both UInt8 variables to Int overrides the default exception on overflow as the resulting Int now has room to fit the sum.

To avoid casting the variables for every operation we would like to overload the operator like this:

```
func + (left: UInt8, right: UInt8) -> Int {
   return Int(left) + Int(right)
}
```

However this will give us a compiler error as the + operator is already defined for adding two UInt8's.

What we could do instead is to [define a custom operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH27-ID46), say ^+ to mean addition of two UInt8's but add them as Int's like so:

```
infix operator ^+ { associativity left precedence 140 }

func ^+ (left: UInt8, right: UInt8) -> Int {
    return Int(left) + Int(right)
}
```

Then we can use it in our algorithms:

```
print(number1 ^+ number3) // Prints 300
```

If you however want the result to just overflow you can use [the overflow operators from the standard library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH27-ID37):

```
print(number1 &+ number3) // Prints 44
```

Answer (score 5):

Girish K Gupta,

UInt8 has max range 0 to 255. Which you can check using `UInt8.min` and `UInt8.max`. Basically 0 to 2 power 8.

Issue with print(number1 + number3) will return 300. 300 is greater then 255 hence crash.

When you add two UInt8 result will be by default casted to UInt8 hence the crash

Finally when you `Int(number1) + Int(number3)` you are forcefully casting number1 and number3 to Int.

When you use Int, range of its value depends on the platform on which you are running it either 32 bit or 64 bit. for example its range can be -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 for 32 bit.

When you add Int to Int result will be typecasted to Int. And believe me 300 is way inside the range :)

As per your question is there a better way to do it :)

Apple's docs clearly specifies and instructs to use Int rather then UInt8 or UInt32 or even UInt64 until and unless using UInt8, UInt32 or UInt64 is absolutely essential.

Here is the quote from apple's doc :)

> “Use UInt only when you specifically need an unsigned integer type
>   with the same size as the platform’s native word size. If this is not
>   the case, Int is preferred, even when the values to be stored are
>   known to be non-negative. A consistent use of Int for integer values
>   aids code interoperability, avoids the need to convert between
>   different number types, and matches integer type inference,”
>
> Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.2).”
>   iBooks. https://itun.es/in/jEUH0.l

So best thing for you to do :) follow apples instruction :) Change the number1,number2 and number3 to Int :) Problem solved :)

Hence no crash :)

Comment: Unfortunately the struct where the UInt8 var is stored belongs to someone else hence I can't change it :( Basically the UInt8s denote RGB values which might be the reason it is stored like that. I am applying some image processing algorithms where I need to manipulate those values but facing these basic issues while doing simple arithmetic operations.

Comment: @girish-k-gupta : Then whatever you are doing is correct :) Int(number1) + Int(number3) but remember by casting it to Int you will get a whole large range range but because you have said its for RGB values now the resultant value that you get after type casting may not make sense :)

Comment: Thanks @Sandeep Bhandari